# Given a list of prime ordered pairs, combine two lines with like terms to create an ordered triplet

Tags: c

Using C, I have generated a list of prime numbers to 10 million and from that list created another list consisting of ordered pairs [x,y] such that the difference of x and y is six.

However, when I try to write a code that generates an output of [x,y,z] triples, or [w,x,y,z] quadruple up to 10 million, my computer simply isn't powerful enough to finish the job in a reasonable amount of time.

My idea is to write a code that opens the text file of ordered pairs, recognizes a repeat number on two separate lines and combines those lines like so:

```
[5, 11]

[11, 17]

[17, 23]

[23, 29]
```

would turn into [5, 11, 17, 23, 29]

How can I do this in C?

edit: Here's my code to generate progressions of 5 numbers that differ by 6:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
freopen("test.txt", "w+", stdout);
    FILE *twinPrimes;
    twinPrimes = fopen("primes.txt", "r");

    //read file into array
    int numberArray[664579];
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    int m;

    for (i = 0; i < 664579; i++)
    {
        fscanf(twinPrimes, "%d", &numberArray[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 664579; i++) {       
    for(j = i+1; j < i+6; j++) {
    for(k = j+1; k < j+6; k++) {
    for(l = k+1; l < k+6; l++) {
    for(m = l+1; m < l+6; m++) {
    if(abs(numberArray[i] - numberArray[j]) == 6) {
    if(abs(numberArray[j] - numberArray[k]) == 6) {
    if(abs(numberArray[k] - numberArray[l]) == 6) {
    if(abs(numberArray[l] - numberArray[m]) == 6) {
        printf("[%d, %d, %d, %d, %d]\n", numberArray[i], numberArray[j], numberArray[k], numberArray[l], numberArray[m]);} } } } } }     }

        }
    }
}
```

However, the problem i'm still having is that I can't generate larger progressions without it slowing down my computer or taking extremely long to finish processing.

I have a text file, however, with a list of ordered pairs of primes that differ by 6. I think a MUCH more efficient code can be made by telling it to take the union of the two lines with a common element as shown above. However, I have no clue where to start with this code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read. Combine. Write. Which part is the problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Please give the code and describe how it fails.

Comment: "  I try to write a code that generates output of [x,y,z] triples, or [w,x,y,z] quadruples up to 10 million ..." --> post that code.

Comment: Give us the algorithm, then your code that implements that algorithm and I am sure that someone will help you and make your code run.

Comment: It's okay for you to post code that doesn't compile, or doesn't work. In fact, that's what you _should_ do. Otherwise, how can we help fix it?

Comment: If you've got the list of primes and you want to generate all the maximal sequences where the successive primes differ by 6, you don't have to generate pairs and then create triples from the pairs, and so on.  You can simply start at a number (5, say), and check all the primes that different by 6 (11, 17, 23, 29)  and simply print those; then return to 7 and print 13, 19; then 11…do you want to print 11 again, or do you skip it?  You probably skip it, so you mark 'used' primes (set them to 0, for example), and continue through the list until you find the triple [31, 37, 43], etc.

Comment: Once you've got the list of primes, generating the maximal sets of 'gap of 6' should be barely over O(N) complexity.

Comment: Updated my code in the original post.

Comment: Can you post a peak of `primes.txt`? Is `numberArray` correctly read?